# PHPunit Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I don't know if it's related to Laravel 5.4. When I run `phpunit` command after installing Laravel 5.4 without making any changes, I get

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration()`

But when I run `php artisan dusk`, it runs normally:

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker
phpunit
```

Output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1046
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1046
Stack trace:
 C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
{main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046
```

---

```
phpunit
```

Output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1046
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1046
Stack trace:
#0    C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ublocker\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1046
```

---

```
php artisan dusk
```

Output:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F.                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It seems like your version installed globally does not meet the minimal required version. Try to run

```
phpunit --version
```

I bet you will get something like `5.1`. The `php artisan dusk` command uses different version which is located in `vendor/bin/phpunit`. So, you are also able to use this version instead. Just type:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

instead of `phpunit`. You have to upgrade your global phpunit version if it works.

Comment: I tried update phpunit globally but still didn't works. I bet my xampp causing this error. Do you how to update phpunit in xampp? They are still using phpunit 3.5.7 version wth

Comment: did you tried to launch it as I said with "vendor/bin/phpunit" in terminal?

Comment: yeah i did and it worked but i still curious how to update it globally. not very convenient to run `vendor\bin\phpunit` every time I run the test, right?

Comment: Next actions is very depends to your operations system. Basically you have to find where is your binary located and replace it with a new one

Comment: you're right. i just remove phpunit related file in xampp\php directory (file and the batch file). it's not conflicted anymore with phpunit on my project

Comment: Official doc to install PhpUnit 5.7, last version for PHP 5.6:
https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/installation.html
Look for text "To globally install the PHAR"

Comment: PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. You loose your bet

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the following command worked in a Windows environment, with `\` in place of `/`:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem in Laravel 5.4. The following worked for me:

Step 1: Update your composer dependencies:

```
composer update
```

Step 2: Run `phpunit`:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You can run a specific test by specifying the file:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php
```

Comment: Yes, you can run **one** specific test. How to run all the test without having access to ```php bin/phpunit``` command ?

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue ans solved with this step:

### Check diff version

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

### Update global phpunit:

if versions not equal update phpunit with

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit:^8
```

### Check versions again

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

Answer (score 3):

For any who is experiencing this, `vendor/bin/phpunit` definitely works but you might want to add this line to your .bashrc or .bash_profile or whatever convenient for you to make it works.

```
PATH="./vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

***tested on Linux only**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with homestead laravel 5.6.
When I ran the *phpunit* command from my user, it worked fine, but when I ran it by *[sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)*, I got that error.

Try to run this command from your user, not *sudo*. Maybe it's working for you too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add vendor/bin to the start of your path.  On Unix like OSes running bash you can add the following to the end of your .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=vendor/bin:$PATH
```

In Windows 10, you can access your `Path` environment variable by accessing **System Properties**, **Advanced** tab  and clicking the *Environment Variables...* button.

Either way, inserting vendor/bin at the front of the path will cause your OS to look for phpunit in ./vendor/bin.  If you're in the root of your laravel project, it'll find the executable included with Laravel.  If not, it'll move on to using the global version.