# How to solve Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration()?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.3, testcase

When I run `phpunit` on the command promp, there exist error like this :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1076
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1076
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1076
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(167): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1076
```

I want to test event to send email is working or not

How can I solve it?

Comment: Looks like you're invoking TestDox. Post your exact command line and your `phpunit.xml` file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868027/phpunit-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-phpunit-util-configurationget

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPunit Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\_Util\_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868027/phpunit-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-phpunit-util-configurationget)